# How can I scale only part of svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I have svg with 2 parts:

```
____________
|    |      |
| p1 |  p2  |
|____|______|
```

How can I save p1 width and scale only p2 width on horizontal scale?
Please suggest me where can I get know about it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with plain SVG.  You would need to either use two SVGs side-by-side, or use Javascript to alter p2 where necessary.